# How to configure connection string for CMS database for failover DB in MSSQL server 2014

Tags: 2013-sp1, web8, content-manager, sdl-tridion, database

Can you please help me to configure a CMS for failover db( MS SQL 2014 ), where do I need to setup CMS db for failover DB. I tried to change under Database settings but it works only with manual switching under SDL Web Content Manager console.

Thanks in advance!!!

Anand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL server 2012 onward provides feature of the listener. The role of the listener is to identify the primary database and replica database. **Listener will always direct the traffic to the primary database.**

> In the SDL web configuration, instead of giving database server name,
>   provide listener name and you should be good to go with.

We had the similar setup and it worked fine with failovers as listener will keep track.

Article to setup listener can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/create-or-configure-an-availability-group-listener-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I will try this and let you know...

Answer (score 2):

Not really a question that is (only) related to SDL Web, since it is directly related to the database in question.

So you should really follow the documentation of the database vendor here, I found the following link for you:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/install/create-a-new-sql-server-failover-cluster-setup

If you want to know how to specify the database connection settings, that is done in the SDL Web Content Manager configuration (MMC Snap-in), more details are to be found in the documentation: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-64A87325-CCDC-44F5-968A-B7589F94E90B

Comment: Thanks for your comment !!! I have already setup of fail-over database, only the question is where can I define the connection string for CM?

Comment: @NaveenAnand can you edit your question and update it with that specific information, that will allow you to get more detailed answers.